# App crash when try to get location with baidu map

Tags: android, mobile, baidu-map

I try to implement baidu map in to my app. I set up everything and it can show a static map. But when I try to get current location, my app crash after when I try to call method mLocationClient.start(). I have setup the api keys, ask for permissions, enable service and put the libraries in the correct place. But this crash is still there. And I cant get any crash information from my Logcat. Anyone has the experience to implement baidu map in your android app?

```
import android.os.Bundle``
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Button
import com.baidu.location.BDAbstractLocationListener
import com.baidu.location.BDLocation
import com.baidu.location.LocationClient
import com.baidu.location.LocationClientOption
import com.baidu.mapapi.CoordType
import com.baidu.mapapi.SDKInitializer
import com.baidu.mapapi.map.*
import com.baidu.mapapi.model.LatLng
import com.starkey.android.newlink.R

class BaiduMapDemoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mMapView: MapView? = null
    private var findLocation: Button? = null
    lateinit var map: BaiduMap
    private var isFirstLoc = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        SDKInitializer.initialize(this)
        SDKInitializer.setCoordType(CoordType.BD09LL)

        setContentView(R.layout.baidu_demo)
        mMapView = findViewById(R.id.bmapView)
        findLocation = findViewById(R.id.addfence) as Button

        map = mMapView!!.map
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        val mCurrentMode = MyLocationConfiguration.LocationMode.FOLLOWING
        val mCurrentMarker = 
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ha_icon)
        val accuracyCircleFillColor = 0xAAFFFF88.toInt()
        val accuracyCircleStrokeColor = 0xAA00FF00.toInt()

        map.setMyLocationConfiguration(MyLocationConfiguration(
                mCurrentMode, true, mCurrentMarker,
                accuracyCircleFillColor, accuracyCircleStrokeColor))
        val mLocationClient = LocationClient(applicationContext)
        val mylistener = MyLocationListenner()

        mLocationClient.registerLocationListener(mylistener)
        val option = LocationClientOption()
        option.locationMode = 
(LocationClientOption.LocationMode.Hight_Accuracy)
        option.setCoorType("bd09ll")
        option.setScanSpan(1000)
        option.openGps = true
        option.setLocationNotify(true)
        option.setIgnoreKillProcess(false)
        option.SetIgnoreCacheException(false)
        option.setWifiCacheTimeOut(5 * 60 * 1000)
        option.setEnableSimulateGps(false)

        mLocationClient.setLocOption(option)

        (findLocation as Button).setOnClickListener {
            mLocationClient.start()
        }

        var test = mLocationClient.isStarted
        mLocationClient.requestLocation()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mMapView!!.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
   
        super.onResume()
        mMapView!!.onResume()

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mMapView!!.onPause()
    }

    inner class MyLocationListenner : BDAbstractLocationListener() {

        override fun onReceiveLocation(location: BDLocation?) {
            if (location == null || mMapView == null)
                return;
            val locData = MyLocationData.Builder()
                    .accuracy(location.radius)
                    .direction(100.toFloat()).latitude(location.latitude)
                    .longitude(location.longitude).build()
            map.setMyLocationData(locData)
            if (isFirstLoc) {
                isFirstLoc = false
                val ll = LatLng(location.latitude,
                        location.longitude)
                val u = MapStatusUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll)
                map.animateMapStatus(u)
            }
        }
        fun onReceivePoi(poiLocation: BDLocation) {
        }
    }
```

Message from Logcat:

> 2019-01-04 13:37:57.483 25394-25394/com.starkey.android.newlink.debug I/System.out: Before call start
>
> 2019-01-04 13:37:59.255 25394-25401/com.starkey.android.newlink.debug E/zygote64: Failed to read JT_BOOLEAN local from register v6 at DEX pc 0x0000014f in method void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>
> 2019-01-04 13:37:59.296 25394-25401/com.starkey.android.newlink.debug E/zygote64: Failed to read JT_BOOLEAN local from register v6 at DEX pc 0x0000014f in method void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>
> 2019-01-04 13:37:59.299 25394-25401/com.starkey.android.newlink.debug E/zygote64: Failed to read JT_INT local from register v9 at DEX pc 0x0000014f in method void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>
> 2019-01-04 13:37:59.305 25394-25401/com.starkey.android.newlink.debug E/zygote64: Failed to read JT_BOOLEAN local from register v12 at DEX pc 0x0000014f in method void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>
> 2019-01-04 13:39:08.749 25394-25394/com.starkey.android.newlink.debug I/System.out: after call start

Comment: Please attach the error log.... the amount of times I've to ask that is unreal lol

Comment: And I cant get any crash information from my Logcat.  Why? This should be a more important question.

Comment: @Nero, that's the frustrating part, I can not get any error log from my Logcat.

Comment: @GenoChen Agreed! Maybe because I am using the Baidu library, so Logcat can not get any error information?

Comment: In my memory (2 years ago), `SDKInitializer.initialize` should use an `ApplicationContext`, `this` inside `Activity` is not enough.

Comment: I have found out what's going on here. After remove the "show only selected application" filter in logcat, I got the error message for the crash. It seems after I call that method, something is wrong with FirebaseApp in my application. Anyway, it was a different issue from baidu map. Turning off the filter really helped me, so I will close this question and mark Geno Chen's answer as the correct one. Thanks everyone for helping and happy coding!

Comment: One more update about this problem just in case someone need to implement baidu map into their app. When you add your service in your manifest file, maybe you dont want to follow the articles to add :  android:process=":remote". Because this was the cause of my crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `SDKInitializer.initialize` should use an `ApplicationContext`, `this` inside `Activity` is not enough.

Use

```
SDKInitializer.initialize(applicationContext)
```

instead of

```
SDKInitializer.initialize(this)
```

Reference: [Hello BaiduMap](http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=androidsdk/guide/create-project/hellomap) (Chinese)

> 4. The referenced `Context` used for initialize SDK during application creation is a global variable;
>
> **Warning: Before using any components in SDK, (you) must call `SDKInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());`. So ee suggest to put this method inside the initialization method of `Application`.**

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have also read this article. I changed this into applicationContext. But the the app still crashes without any information.

Comment: @Y.D Blind debugging... I am trying to brain compile your code to see if there are any errors :-(

Comment: @Y.D Have you tried reading the [demo](http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=androidsdk/sdkandev-download)? Read `LocationDemo` to see if there is something you accidently missing.

Comment: I have downloaded their demo code, copy paste their code and still have the similiar problem. The strange thing is that there are a lot of articles in Chinese about different problems but none of them is about the mLocationClient.start() crashes app problem.

Comment: @Y.D I'm so sure there is some logcat output, because I just tried opening the demo of BaiduMap LBS Demo 4.4.1. Do your app's crash generate REALLY not generate something like stacktrace or JNI error output?

Comment: Yeah. That's the confusing part. I add a break point before excuting that line of code, clear my logcat, then hit continue. My app crashed right after this without providing any error info. My collegue stopped by too and also very confused by this.

Comment: @Y.D Or, could you please try a stupid method, print log in **every** line, use the last output to locate the line containing error? Or, `Step Into` the `.start` call to see its internals?

Comment: I'm not sure if the earlier `.requestLocation` than `.start` is the question... There is no usage in demo like this....

Comment: I am using show only selected application as my filter, am I using the wrong one? Or should I just close filter?

Comment: in demo LocationActivity class. line 103:  locationService.start();// 定位SDK  is kind of doing the same thing. I just change the variable name, but basicly the same object.

Comment: I have removed my filter and add two print message and have update my question with the new info I got from Logcat.

Comment: @Y.D As you see in the first several lines, there are something unexpected thrown by `zygote64`, you can see a same process id.

Answer (score 0):

please remove .jar & .so file from libs & jinLibs lfolder & add below api in app.gragle

```
implementation 'com.baidu.mapapi:base:3.7.1'
implementation 'com.baidu.mapapi:map:3.7.1'
implementation 'com.baidu.mapapi:search:3.7.1'
implementation 'com.baidu.mapapi:util:3.7.1'
```

now, fixed SDKInitializer.initialize(applicationContext)  crashed issue.